# angularjs - controller service rest calls

Tags: angularjs

I've been avoiding asking this here as there are loads of examples out there but I have no idea what's I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to put a little angular app in place but I'm struggling to get it working pass the very basics.

I want to get a little CRUD happening but using a reasonable clean structure that I could use as a template for other apps. I've found millions of examples but only using controllers and I found millions of examples on how to implement and DI services. I'm now trying to put them together but no joy.

Here we go.

I have a simple **accounts.html**

```
<h1>Accounts</h1>

<div ng-controller="AccountController">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>number</td>
                <td>accountType</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="acct in accounts">
                <td>{{acct.name}}</td>
                <td>{{acct.description}}</td>
                <td>{{acct.number}}</td>
                <td>{{acct.accountType}}</td>
                <td>{{delete(acct)}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div>
        <div>
            Name:<input type="text" ng-model="account.name">
        </div>
        <div>
            Description:<input type="text"
                ng-model="account.description">
        </div>
        <div>
            Number:<input type="text" ng-model="account.number">
        </div>
        <div>
            Account Type:<select ng-model="account.accountType">
                <option ng-repeat="acctType in accountTypes">{{acctType}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="save()">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Angular JS -->
<script src="assets/thirdparty/angular/1.4.8/js/angular.js"></script>

<!-- App Angular JS -->
<script src="assets/local/js/angular/accounts-app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/local/js/angular/controller/AccountController.js"></script>
<script src="assets/local/js/angular/service/RefDataService.js"></script>
```

An **AccountController.js**

```
(function() {

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('accounts-app', ['account-service']);
app.controller('AccountController', ['$scope', 'RefDataService', function($scope, RefDataService) {

    $scope.accountTypes = RefDataService.refData.accountTypes;

    var account = {
        'name' : '',
        'description' : '',
        'number' : '',
        'accountType' : ''
    };

    $scope.account = account;
    $scope.accounts = [];

    $scope.save = function save() {
        $scope.accounts.push(this.account);
        $scope.account = {
            'name' : '',
            'description' : '',
            'number' : '',
            'accountType' : ''
        };

    };

}]);

})();
```

And a **RefDataService.js**

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    var serviceModule = angular.module('account-service', []);

    serviceModule.service ('RefDataService', ['$http', 
        function($http) {
            var url = 'http://localhost:8080/accounts-rest/api/refdata';

            var refData = {};

            refData.accountTypes = {};
            refData.accountTypes = function() {
                return $http.get(url + '/accounttypes');
            }

            return refData;

    }]);
})();
```

I'm trying to load the account types from the rest and populate the select dropdown. I've tried and changed everything I could to make it happen but I either get a console error or no error but an empty dropdown as well.

Ideally, in a real application, this refDataService would load, as the name says, reference data. Advice on how to improve it are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use accountTypes as an object/array:

```
$scope.accountTypes = RefDataService.refData.accountTypes;
```

...but you've defined it as a function in your controller:

```
refData.accountTypes = function() {
    return $http.get(url + '/accounttypes');
}
```

Additionally, it looks like you're expecting `$http.get()` to return the data directly - it actually returns a promise with the response of the request as an argument. You need to use it like this (assuming your REST call returns the object you need):

```
$http.get(url + "accounttypes").then(function (response) {
    refData.accountTypes = response;
});
```

Comment: Yes. If I call accounts-rest/api/refdata/accounttypes directly on my browser, it returns ["type1","type2","type3"]

Comment: @JúliusRetzer Not really. I'm not sure what to change... My JS skill go as far as JQuery to manipulate elements.

Comment: Then yeah, I'd say the best approach would be to create a `loadAccountTypes` function within RefDataService which handles updating the state of the accountTypes array.

Although be careful - the way you're binding your array to the scope now (`$scope.accountTypes = RefDataService.refData.accountTypes;`) means that if the array gets replaced within your service, the version in your scope won't update, as it's still referencing the old version. You're better off doing `$scope.refData = RefDataService.refData;`

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll put together some example code for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u1az5zj6/3/ - Obviously it won't fully function, as the HTTP request is looking for a URL that doesn't exist, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction. The main mistake I found in your code was that you are returning `refData` from your service function and expecting this to equal `RefDataService.refData` in your controller, when in reality whatever you return in the service function will _become_ the service. I'd recommend running through the tutorial on the Angular website - it covers a lot of this stuff!

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Július Retzer's answer, actually, his code example is a little better than mine.

Comment: Yep. Now it's working. Also it needs to be response.data. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U8SeUSKfEZU3BXkGFC6H).

```
app.controller('AccountController', ['$scope', 'RefDataService', function($scope, RefDataService) {
RefDataService.accountTypes().then(function(response){
  $scope.accountTypes = response;
});

$scope.account = {
    'name' : '',
    'description' : '',
    'number' : '',
    'accountType' : ''
};
$scope.accounts = [];

$scope.save = function save() {
    $scope.accounts.push($scope.account);
    $scope.account = {
        'name' : '',
        'description' : '',
        'number' : '',
        'accountType' : ''
    };

};

}]);

var serviceModule = angular.module('account-service', []);

serviceModule.service ('RefDataService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/accounts-rest/api/refdata';

        this.accountTypes = function() {
            return $http.get(url + '/accounttypes');
        }
}]);
```

Things I changed:

- Your RefDataService declaration looked more like factory than service (you should read about the difference for example [here])([AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)). `Module.service` expects a constructor function which is on injection invoked with `new` operator so here I attach `accountTypes` method to this
- In your controller you then use the service as Joe Clay described in his answer
- I fixed `$scope.accounts.push(this.account);` to `$scope.accounts.push($scope.account);`. You would use `this.account` if you were using the [controllerAs syntax](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax).

Comment: Joe's last comment helped getting working but your answer also gave me another perceptive. Also, response is the promise as Joe said, we need to get the data from that.